# Providing dynamic paddin-lfet style to nested LI's

Tags: html, css, html-lists, stylesheet

Here in my css I have given style padding(1.5rem,3rem,4.5rem,6rem) to its LI's by each nesting, but this is something hard coded, my nesting can go to N numbers, so this approach i can not use, Is there was better approach i can handle this with CSS ?

```css
.parent ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0 }
li { margin:0; padding: 0; cursor:pointer}
li a {display: block;}

.container ul a  {padding-left:1.5rem}
.container ul ul a  {padding-left:3rem}
.container ul ul ul a  {padding-left:4.5rem}
.container ul ul ul ul a  {padding-left:6rem}

li a:hover {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="parent" id="Head">
    <li class="items"><a><span>AAA</span></a></li>
    <li class="items"> 
        <div class="group"><a><span>BBBB</span></a> </div>
        <ul class="group-item">
           <li class="items"><a><span>bbbbb</span></a></li>
           <li class="items"><a><span>bbbbb</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
        <div class="group"><a><span>CCCC</span></a></div>
        <ul class="group-item">
          <li class="items"><a><span>cccc</span></a></li>
          <li class="items"><a><span>cccc</span></a></li>
          <li class="items">
             <div class="group"> <a><span>cccc</span></a> </div>
             <ul class="group-item">
                <li class="items"><a><span>cccc1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items"><a><span>cccc1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items">
                   <div class="group"> <a><span>cccc1</span></a> </div>
                    <ul class="group-item">
                      <li class="items"><a><span>cccc2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a><span>cccc2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a><span>cccc2</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks Only solution left is using javascript

```js
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
var allUls= parents[0].querySelectorAll('ul');
allUls.forEach(function(x,i){
  var i = i+1;
  var y = x.querySelectorAll('.sid');
   y.forEach(function(x1){
     x1.style.paddingLeft = 1.5 * i+'rem';
  })
})
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0 }
li { margin:0; padding: 0; cursor:pointer}
li a {display: block;}


li a:hover {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="parent" id="Head">
    <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>A</span></a></li>
    <li class="items"> 
        <div class="group"><a class="sid"><span>B</span></a> </div>
        <ul class="group-item">
           <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>b</span></a></li>
           <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>b</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
        <div class="group"><a class="sid"><span>C</span></a></div>
        <ul class="group-item">
          <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c</span></a></li>
          <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c</span></a></li>
          <li class="items">
             <div class="group"> <a class="sid"><span>c</span></a> </div>
             <ul class="group-item">
                <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items">
                   <div class="group"> <a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a> </div>
                    <ul class="group-item">
                      <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```